# What can cause a GAN to generate images that look different than those provided in the training set

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I have implemented Improved **WGAN-GP algorithm** using keras. The dataset used is a gray-scale **open street network images**.

The training after some epochs produces undesired (or simply different than expected) patterns.

For example the real image looks like this (32 images plotted using 8x4 grid)
[image]

While the generated image looks like this (16 images plotted using 8X2 grid)
[image]

***NOTE*** : This was collected after 450 epochs with each epoch split into 22 batches. You can find my model implemented using keras [here](https://gist.github.com/bhavyalatha26/b88f080d220b3e032b7ff9e5c41da534)

While the results are expected to look like road networks with lanes (lines and dots), they instead look like closed curves (like a country or continent maps)

I have tried most of the tips and tricks suggested for training of a GAN like :

1. **Dropouts** to avoid overfitting problems
2. **Label smoothing** to avoid
   overconfidence problems
3. **Wasserstein and gradient penalty** cost
   functions to address mode collapses
4. **Increased kernel sizes** for
   faster convergence
5. **Training the discriminator more** number of times
   than the generator

But none seem to work. I am not sure on how to debug this issue as I do not understand which hyper parameter of a GAN can cause this kind of issue.

If any one faced similar kind of issue while training GANs, please help me understand what can cause this and which hyper paramerter needs to be tuned.

TIA.

Comment: "I do not understand which hyper parameter of a GAN can cause this kind of issue."  This is a backwards question.  The question to ask is "Why should I expect a GAN to work for this type of problem?"  IMHO, GANs learn "general patterns".  Road networks are *mostly* continuous curves.  Dead ends and intersections are the exception.  Thus, when the GAN is producing a network, it has a bit of road and asks itself 'what should stuff "nearby" look like?'  The answer, based on the training data, is "more continuous road."

Comment: So, if you want to get more "dead ends", you need to find a way to have the discriminator "expect" them.  This doesn't seem to me to be a trivial problem.

Comment: Hi @Scott, thank you for the response. So do you mean GAN is still working as expected but generates more continuous  than dead ends ?

Comment: "you need to find a way to have the discriminator "expect" them" , how can we generally achieve this ? 
Like if I want a GAN to look into more finer details of a given input image set, what changes would help, any idea ?

Comment: I mean that such a thing is possible.  Your generative network is producing something that fools the discriminator.  The generative network is a convolutional-type-thing, so it likes to produce things that look a particular way locally.  The discriminator is also a convolutional-type-thing, so it likes to classify things based on how they look locally.  If locally-continuous is 99% of how road networks look, then that will account for 99% of the GANs decision-making strategy.

Comment: Find a way to quantify intersections and dead-ends, and add a penalty term to your discriminator when images don't have them, would be one cheap way to do so.  You might also iterate on your dataset by hand-labeling the "country maps" as "fake" and train your discriminator for a while (disconnected from the generator) to recognize them as "fake".  There are probably other options, and I have reached the limit of my qualifications in advice at this point.  :)